# MongoEngine validate choices within ListField

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Is it possible to use the choices option of a field object (in my case StringField) which is being used as an argument to ListField?

I’m trying to define a property on a collection like this:

```
my_list_property = ListField(StringField(choices=CHOICES), required=True)
```

and I am wanting MongoEngine to validate that the elements of my_list_property are in CHOICES on save.

---

**EDIT** - from comments

Having looked at the MongoEngine code, `ListField` inherits from `ComplexBaseField`. The validate method on `ComplexBaseField` calls validate on `self.field` (in my case, this is `StringField`).

`StringField` inherits from `BaseField`. `BaseField.validate` just passes.

When a `BaseField` e.g. `StringField` is the parent field, `BaseField._validate` is called as opposed to `BaseField.validate`, and `._validate` does validation on choices. I wonder if `ComplexBaseField.validate` should actually call `self.field._validate` instead?

Comment: Having looked at the MongoEngine code, ListField inherits from ComplexBaseField. The validate method on ComplexBaseField calls validate on self.field (in my case, this is StringField). StringField inherits from BaseField. BaseField.validate just passes. When a BaseField e.g. StringField is the parent field, BaseField._validate is called as opposed to BaseField.validate, and ._validate does validation on choices. I wonder if ComplexBaseField.validate should actually call self.field._validate instead.

Comment: It's pretty much related to this PR on mongoengine repo: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/pull/1584

Hope will it be approved and merged